# flutter material.dart and pubspec.yaml file error

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I got such errors when I was developing my first flutter application. I downloaded github projects (flutter first app examples), created a new project myself. I've been searching for 2 hours and still can't solve my problems:( please help! I updated flutter from terminal, I used

```
flutter doctor, 
flutter upgrade
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

none of my problems are solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have just downloaded the main.dart file which is not enough for the application to work it also contain other files and folders which I didn't saw in the picture

Answer (score 0):

I guess this isn't a flutter project!

let's say you installed flutter correctly and you added the path.

navigate to your folder when you want to create your first flutter project and run cmd
in the terminal run, this command  `flutter create my_first_project`
or any name you want.

in vs code opens the folder you've just created (my_first_project)and you're good to start.

android emulator must be installed!

Answer (score 0):

run `flutter doctor -v` and figure out if the issue is in the code or with flutter installation, ...

Answer (score 0):

**##** Copy the **HTTPS link from Git Code** without downloading the project **from GitHub**, **install Git Apps**, Open Git Brush write **Git clone** Paste HTTPS Copy Link then **enter**.
Download Git Apps Link https://git-scm.com/download/win

**Follow the pictures**... **hopeful solve your problem.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]